# Is there a correct way to handle stream error in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to catch an error in the controller and send status(500) to the front-end to let the user know that there is a streaming error. But for some reason the error is not caught and I am sending status(200) to the user. Let me know if i am doing something wrong.

**file - utils.js**

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';
import ck from 'ckey';

export const stream = (term, clients, twitterStream) => {
  const twitter = new Twitter({
    // subdomain: 'api', // "api" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    // version: '1.1', // version "1.1" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    version: '2', // version "1.1" is the default (change for v2)
    extension: false, // true is the default (this must be set to false for v2 endpoints)
    consumer_key: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    access_token_secret: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  });

  let stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term });

  stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
    console.log('tweetsJohn: ');
    broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(tweet));
  });

  stream.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('stream error: ', error.source);
  });

  twitterStream = stream;
  return twitterStream;
};

const broadcast = (clients, message) => {
  clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**controller**

```
import { stream } from './utils.js';

// Sets search term for twitter stream.
export const setSearchTerm = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { term } = req.params;
    console.log('setSearchTerm');
    console.log('term: ', term);
    if (twitterStream) {
      console.log('getTweetPause');
      twitterStream.destroy();
    }
    twitterStream = stream(term, req.app.locals.clients, twitterStream);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successful search request' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
    // res.status(500).json({ ex: 'Internal Server Errorr' });
  }
};
```

**Solution**

**file-utils.js**

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';
import ck from 'ckey';

export const stream = (clients, term) => {
  const twitter = new Twitter({
    // subdomain: 'api', // "api" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    // version: '1.1', // version "1.1" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    version: '2', // version "1.1" is the default (change for v2)
    extension: false, // true is the default (this must be set to false for v2 endpoints)
    consumer_key: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    access_token_secret: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  });

  let currentStream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term });

  const streamResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    currentStream.on('data', function (tweet) {
      console.log('tweets: ');
      broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(tweet));
      resolve(tweet);
    });

    currentStream.on('error', function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
  });

  return { currentStream, streamResult };
};

const broadcast = (clients, message) => {
  clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**controller**

```
import { stream } from './utils.js';

let twitterStream;

// Sets search term for twitter stream.
export const setSearchTerm = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { term } = req.params;

    console.log('setSearchTerm');
    console.log('term: ', term);

    if (twitterStream) {
      console.log('getTweetPause');
      twitterStream.destroy();
    }

    const { currentStream, streamResult } = stream(
      req.app.locals.clients,
      term
    );
    twitterStream = currentStream;

    await streamResult;

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successful HTTP request' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error catch: ');
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
};
```

Comment: if you use throw error in `  stream.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('stream error: ', error.source);
  });` is incorrect?

Comment: triggerUncaughtException

Comment: [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Response>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Comment: You did not design any method for the `stream()` function to communicate back either when it was complete or if it had an error.  It needs to either return a promise that is connected to its completion/error or if needs to take a callback that the caller can use to know when its done.  You `stream()` function returns LONG before it has completed.  So, you aren't getting results or error from its return value.

Comment: @jfriend00 I do get the stream but I am having problems handling the error correctly. Whenever I am getting one it is treated as status(200) instead of status(500)

Comment: Did you read the question yours is marked a duplicate of?  It explains there why you cannot directly return your result or error.  Your function returns BEFORE you have a result or error.  Thus, all it returns is junk.  You have to either return a promise that is connected to your asynchronous operation or you have to accept a callback that you call when your asynchronous operation is complete and you pass error or result to the callback.

Comment: @jfriend00  ```const errorMessage = await stream.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('stream error: ', error);
     return error;
  });```

Comment: Stop guessing.  You need to LEARN how to do this stuff.  `await` only does something useful when you're awaiting a promise that is connected to your asynchronous operation and `stream.on()` does not return a promise.  You will need to spend some time learning.  Start by reading and studying the accepted answer to the question yours is marked a duplicate of.  If you study that and attempt to implement one of the ideas there and get stuck, then you can post a new question with your attempt.  But, don't just guess how to do this.  Read, learn, study.

Comment: Go learn how promises work.  Learn how to promisify a stream operation.  Then, you can apply that knowledge to this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I am reading the question. You are right. I need to understand instead of guessing.

Comment: @jfriend00 added the solution to the question.